# Confusion about variable in python. How python use variables?

Tags: python

When I run this,

```py
key=[[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1]]
key_=[[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1]]
m=3
for i_ in range(1,m+1):
    for j_ in range(1,m+1):
        key[j_-1][m+1-i_-1]=key_[i_-1][j_-1]
print(key,key_,sep='\n')
```

I got this:

```
>>> [[0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]]
[[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1]]
```

However, when I changed only the second line,

```py
key=[[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1]]
key_=key
m=3
for i_ in range(1,m+1):
    for j_ in range(1,m+1):
        key[j_-1][m+1-i_-1]=key_[i_-1][j_-1]
print(key,key_,sep='\n')
```

I got this:

```
>>> [[0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
[[0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

Why do the two codes have different results?
In my opinion, they should be same.
Why the different parts make different results?

Comment: In your second example `key_` is the same as `key`. So modifying one of those alters the other too.

Comment: Lists are mutable. Do `id(key)` and `id(key_)` in both cases - in the second case, both your names point to the same object.

Comment: Code/question style

Comment: This is explained here: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, variables which contain lists are more like pointers. When you say `key_=key`, you're telling Python to use the **same** list in both cases, not a copy. If you want a copy of the original list, use `key_=[x.copy() for x in key]`. This will copy the contents of each item (which are lists) in `key`.

**Examples:**

Make two lists which contain 1, 2 and 3

```
>>> my_list = [1,2,3]
>>> my_list
[1, 2, 3]
>>> my_list2 = my_list
>>> my_list2
[1, 2, 3]
```

Now let's edit the value of the original list...

```
>>> my_list[0] = 10
>>> my_list
[10, 2, 3]
>>> my_list2
[10, 2, 3]
```

The changes are copied because `my_list` and `my_list2` are the **same**, not just a copy of it.

Let's change `my_list2`:

```
>>> my_list2[1] = 20
>>> my_list2
[10, 20, 3]
>>> my_list
[10, 20, 3]
```

And once again, the values are updated between the two as they both point to the same list.

Now let's see what happens if we use the `copy` method:

```
>>> my_list_copy = my_list.copy()
>>> my_list_copy
[10, 20, 3]
>>> my_list[0] = 1
>>> my_list
[1, 20, 3]
>>> my_list_copy
[10, 20, 3]
```

And so we can see that the two lists start with the same contents, but are different.

Using the `is` operator, we can also see this difference between the 3 list variables:

```
>>> my_list is my_list2
True
>>> my_list is my_list_copy
False
>>>
```

**EDIT:**

`key` is a list containing lists as items. When the `copy` method is called, only the outer list is copied, so the actual items in both lists (ie the sub-lists) are identical. To copy these by value rather than effectively by reference, we can use a simple list comprehension:

```
key_=[x.copy() for x in key]
```

This code copies each item in `key` by value, and creates a new list with these as items.

The output using this is

```
[[0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]]
[[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: Now you have to explain why changing `key_ = key` to `key_ = key.copy()` in th OPs code doesn't change anything in the output ...

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I have now fixed my answer.